# Array Types in .NET and difference between "is" and "=="

Tags: c#

After reading Jeffrey Richter's great article [Array Types in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985948.aspx)
I realized, that inheritance of C# arrays (`Int32[]`, `String[]` etc.) can not be visualized. I mean, in VS I can not see base class of these arrays.

And another interesting thing:

```
bool b1 = Type.GetType("System.Int32[]").BaseType == typeof(System.Array);
bool b2 = Type.GetType("System.Int32[]").BaseType is System.Array;
```

But `b1` and `b2` are not the same: `b1` is `true` and `b2` is `false`.

How to deal with this "magic" and which other same "magics" C#.NET have?

Comment: The value returned from `.BaseType` is an instance of `System.Type` so is not an instance of `System.Array`. `obj is T` returns whether the object `obj` is an instance of the type `T`. In your first test you are comparing two `System.Type` instances for equality. This behaviour is not specific to arrays and array types.

Comment: It's not "magic" just pure logical sense. You're expecting that `bool b1 = System.Type == System.Type;` and then `bool b2 = System.Type is System.Array;` which makes no sense.

Comment: In short, you misunderstood either what `is` does or what `Type`, the class, is

Comment: The `is` operator checks the actual types at runtime; the `typeof` operator creates an instance of `System.Type` which so to speak 'represents' the runtime type which can be access by program logic. That specific instance of `System.Type`, in a certain way, _is_ not the runtime type itself.

Answer (score 2):

Operator `is` compares if an object is compatible with, or can be cast into certain type.
Operator `==` is equality operator, it checks if two objects are equal.

Take a look at this example

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
bool b = list is IList; //true
bool b2 = list.GetType() == typeof(IList<string>); //false
```

First `bool` variable is `true` because `List<string>` can be cast to `IList<string>` (in fact, it **is** `IList<string>` because it implements that interface). Second one is `false` because `GetType()` returns `System.Collections.Generic.List`1`which is not equal to`IList`